# For all $a$ and $b$ in $B$, $(a \times b) + a = a$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

In the statements below, $B$ is a boolean algebra with $×$ and $+$ for binary operations.

3.)   For all $a$ and $b$ in $B$, $(a ×b) + a = a$.

This is what I have as an answer.  Can someone confirm or deny this logic?  I am supposed to prove this.  I am also having some trouble with Boolean algebra so I just wanted to make sure that I'm doing this right.

We can simplify ($a ×b) + a$  to  $ab+a$.
$=a(1+b)$ 
$=a×1$ because for all $b∈B, \ \ \ b+1=1$ because of the Universal Bound Law 
$=a$

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good. (Except, LaTexify it next time! :-))

Comment: how do you do that again?

Comment: @JacobHuskisson Put dollar signs around equations - e.g.: $x^{x+y}$ is given by `x^{x+y}`, e.t.c. Fractions are $\frac{a}{b}$ - `\frac{a}{b}`.